# Want to make Selenium pause for input or click that will take me to another page and then resume again from next page (in case element not found)?

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I'm absolute new to VBA Selenium and want to write a programme that

1. will open a website login and then add a form in it by click on "+" sign
2. Form will show two boxes, in first box I have to fetch text from first record of column/row, copy in box and click save.
3. repeat the 2nd step until all the text in excel sheet are copied and saved.

problem is I am not able to find the element to click the button after entering the email? (below is html code)

```
<button class="ui-button ui-button--primary ui-button--full-width ui-button--size-large  captcha__submit" type="submit" name="commit" data-disable="true" data-bind-disabled="captchaDisabled" define="{localClass: new CaptchaStateHandler($context, {
                            v2Completed: true,
                            v3EnterpriseCompleted: false,
                            formCompleted: true,
                          })}" enable_submit_onload="true">Continue with Email</button>
```

My Selenium VBA code is below.

```
Option Explicit
Dim driver As New Selenium.WebDriver


Sub langify()

Dim webpage As String
Dim shopifypage As String
Dim login As String
Dim password_ As String
Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
Dim keys As New Selenium.keys



driver.Start "chrome"
driver.Get "https://v2.langify-app.com/"

webpage = Sheet3.Range("H1").Text
shopifypage = Sheet3.Range("H2").Text
login = Sheet3.Range("H3").Text
password_ = Sheet3.Range("H4").Text

AppActivate ("CHROME")

'login-form-left

driver.FindElementById("form_shop_url").Click shopifypage
driver.FindElementById("form_install").Click
driver.FindElementByCss("#account_email").SendKeys login
**driver.FindElementByCss("#body-content > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.page-main > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > form > button", 15000).Click** ' this code is not working, appears to be wrong.
'alternate way by xpath which is throughing runtime error 0 and element click detected

driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class=""ui-button ui-button--primary ui-button--full-width ui-button--size-large  captcha__submit""]", 10000).Click

'driver.FindElementByCss("#account_password", 150000).SendKeys password_


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Dim driver As New Selenium.WebDriver


Sub langify()

Dim webpage As String
Dim shopifypage As String
Dim login As String
Dim password_ As String
Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
Dim keys As New Selenium.keys
Dim button As Selenium.WebElement
Dim html As HTMLDocument

driver.Start "chrome"
driver.Get "https://v2.langify-app.com/"

webpage = Sheet3.Range("H1").Text
shopifypage = Sheet3.Range("H2").Text
login = Sheet3.Range("H3").Text
password_ = Sheet3.Range("H4").Text

AppActivate ("CHROME")

'login-form-left

driver.FindElementById("form_shop_url").Click shopifypage
driver.FindElementById("form_install").Click
driver.FindElementByCss("#account_email").SendKeys login

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class=""ui-button ui-button--primary ui-button--full-width ui-button--size-large  captcha__submit""]", 10000).Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:3"))
driver.FindElementByCss("#account_password", 8000).SendKeys password_

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:5"))

driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class=""ui-button ui-button--primary ui-button--full-width ui-button--size-large  captcha__submit""]", 10000).Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"))

driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class=""ui-button ui-button--primary ui-button--full-width  captcha__submit""]", 10000).Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

'driver.FindElementByClass("ui-button ui-button--primary ui-button--size-large").Click

driver.FindElementByLinkText("Continue setup").Click

'driver.SwitchToWindowByName(

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).